# Why does the support of measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ exist?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

> DEFINITION : The support of a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, written spt $\mu$, is the smallest closed set such that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus X)=0$.

Why does this set exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It exists because the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable$^1$.

By definition, the complement of the support of $\mu$ is the largest open set $U$ with $\mu(U) = 0$. Showing the existence of that set, and of the support of $\mu$ are equivalent.

So consider the family $\mathscr{V} = \{ V\subset \mathbb{R}^n : V\text{ open}, \mu(V) = 0\}$.

Then $U = \bigcup \mathscr{V}$ is an open set, and $U$ contains every open set with measure $0$. It remains to see that indeed $\mu(U) = 0$. That is where second-countability comes into play: Since the topology is second-countable, $U$ is in fact the union of a *countable* subfamily $\mathscr{V}_0$ of $\mathscr{V}$, and hence

$$\mu(U) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{V\in\mathscr{V}_0} V\right) \leqslant \sum_{V\in\mathscr{V}_0}\mu(V) = 0.$$

Note that we don't need to demand that $\mu$ be a Borel measure, there is always at least one open measurable set with measure $0$, namely $\varnothing$, and since only measurable open sets occur in $\mathscr{V}$, it follows that $U$ is measurable as a countable union of measurable (open) sets.

In general topological or metric spaces, there need not exist a smallest closed set whose complement has measure $0$:

Let $Y$ be an uncountable set with the discrete topology, and let

$$\mu(A) = \begin{cases} 0 &, A\text{ is at most countable}\\ \infty &, A\text{ is uncountable}.\end{cases}$$

Admittedly not the most interesting or useful measure, but it serves well as a counterexample to several things.

Then $\mu$ has no support (if the support is defined as the smallest closed set whose complement has measure $0$), since for every (closed) subset $S\subset Y$ with $\mu(Y\setminus S) = 0$ there is a proper subset $T\subsetneqq S$ with $\mu(Y\setminus T) = 0$, e.g. $T = S\setminus \{s\}$ will do for any $s\in S$.

---

$^1$ A separable metric space is second countable: Let $X$ be a separable metric space, and $D = \{x_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ a countable dense subset. Then $$\mathscr{B} = \{B_{2^{-k}}(x_n) : n,k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

is a countable basis of the topology of $X$.

Since $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable, the family $\mathscr{B}$ is countable. To see it is a basis of the topology, we must see that for every open set $U$ and every $x\in U$ there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ with $x \in B \subset U$. But if $U$ is open and $x\in U$, there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \subset U$. Choose $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{1-k} < \varepsilon$. Since $D$ is dense, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x_n \in B_{2^{-k}}(x)$. Then by symmetry of the metric we have $x\in B_{2^{-k}}(x_n)$, and by the triangle inequality $B_{2^{-k}}(x_n) \subset B_{2^{1-k}}(x) \subset B_\varepsilon(x) \subset U$.

Thus $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of the topology.

For $\mathbb{R}^n$, a canonical choice for the countable dense subset is $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: Where can I find the proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable as I have never seen this before?

Comment: It should be for example proved in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". But it's easy to prove yourself - if you have practically no experience in such matters, the most difficult thing is to get used to the concepts - the family of open balls with rational radius and centre in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is a countable basis of the topology. It's a basis because $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then looking at the proof shows that every separable metric space is second countable, since nothing used the particulars of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{Q}^n$. Would you like to try to prove ...

Comment: ... it yourself, or would you prefer if I add a proof to the answer?

Comment: Proof added. I didn't prove that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, should I add that proof too?

Answer (score 2):

Is the intersection of all the closed sets such that... And can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

$${\rm spt } \mu = \bigcap\left\{S \colon S \text{ is closed and } \mu(S^c)=0\right\}$$
exists, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be an example of a set $S$.

Comment: Seems that this proof applies to any topological space

Comment: I don't think this proof applies to an arbitrary topological space. The right-hand side might not be the smallest closed set whose complement has measure 0. The right-hand side is clearly closed. But I don't think it's complement necessarily has measure 0.